# Android transfer object data through different device, same app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-transfer

I want to implement a feature in an app where users can add friends and check and compare each other stats from the java objects created, which involves a few subclasses.

I was wondering if anyone know what the best way to approach this would be?

The only thing that pops out is using Firebase. Where the user would click a button to upload the data to Firebase with a UUID link, and then give the UUID to the other user, where he/she would have to manually type the UUID in a textfield, and it gets the data from Firebase.

Would method be viable and is there any other better options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a file (you can invent any ending) with all info you need displayed in json. That file can be shared via Whatsapp or what ever and imported in your app?

But I don't know what "stats" that are that the users can compare but I think they will change from time to time? So I would guess an online service would be better because otherwise to update, they have to share again and again?